# Apple CoreAudio on iOS: synthesis to Reverb2 AudioUnit to RemoteIO

Tags: core-audio, audiounit, remoteio

I've successfully been synthesizing 16-bit linear PCM and outputing it to the RemoteIO AudioUnit. Now I'm trying to add a Reverb2 Audio Unit prior to outputing to RemoteIO.  I'm creating an AudioGraph and setting the callback to the Reverb Unit, but I'm not getting any sound.

How do I setup the graph and properly format the Reverb2 and RemoteIO units?

Answer (score 0):

For a basic setup like :

A -> Reverb -> RIO

You need to make sure both AudioStreamBasicDescriptions of the output of A and input of RIO are set to the Reverbs AudioStreamBasicDescriptions. I found the Reverb Audio Unit doesn't support changing formats.